# Generate ms word document using PhpWord

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office, phpword

I'm going to generate some document using PhpWord, I have some draft document where I set `client_name` dynamically.

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($draftUrl);
$templateProcessor->setValue("client_name", $clientName);

$filename = '30.docx';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);
```

then I read this file and user can download it

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
readfile($filename);
```

when I try to open it via **MsOffice** I have this message:
[image]

when I click ***OK***:
[image]

and after accepting this finally I see my document ready. What do I need to generate readable document?

Comment: Have you tried to open the word file in a text editor? Maybe some html output did get into the file and corrupted it.

Comment: I tried to open with wordpad and there is unreadable symbols

Comment: but there is no any html output in the document. After accepting this msword recovering document becomes as desired

Comment: Couple of suggestions to try:  1) adding the content length: `header("Content-Length: ".filesize(basename($filename)));` and/or 2) adding the specific mime type `header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');`. If these don't make any difference, does your code work if you comment out the template value setting? I.e. to pinpoint whether problem is caused by the template & the file serving (more likely) or by invalid content in the setting (less likely)...

Comment: @ejuhjav thank you! I solved problem and put the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) to my code before read and everything works fine.

> This function discards the contents of the output buffer.
>
> This function does not destroy the output buffer like ob_end_clean()
>   does.

so I ensured that undesired output will not get into the generated document.

```
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor($draftUrl);
$templateProcessor->setValue("client_name", $clientName);

$filename = '30.docx';
$templateProcessor->saveAs($filename);

header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='$filename'");
ob_clean();
readfile($filename);
```

Comment: @pat-och Please do not add "edited" comments when editing questions or answers. If and when such a record was edited is always visible below the answer or question.

Comment: sure but i got "Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?" when i just want improve code formatting for 2 lines ... so how to do this kind of improvement ?